# Where should I save gcloud credentials with django

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage, credentials

I want to create a simple API, that provides an unique endpoint for a POST request which  take a json as a parameter, and upload this json in a bucket to google storage.

To do the job, I am using Django framework.

I would like to understand the best practices and patterns on how should I structure my api app to do that, and where should I store the gcloud credentials.
*(By the way, I'm open to suggestions on other (better) ways/technos/frameworks/patterns to do this kind of API)*

For the moment, I am using google.cloud package and putting all the stuff on the **apps.py** file ;

```
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('credentials.json')
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
```

then in the **views.py** file, I'm doing the post function definition, using the bucket defined in the apps.py file.

```
class upload_to_bucket(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            json_file = json.loads(request.body)
            blob = ApiConfig.bucket.blob(json_file['name'])
            blob.upload_from_string(
              data=json.dumps(json_file['json_file_to_upload']),
              content_type='application/json'
            )

            return Response(json_file['json_file_to_upload'])
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Where are you hosting  your API?

Comment: In a google cloud server

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/secrets-management) to store credentials, but other than that, I see no issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your application, you don't need a service account key file. You can use [ADC (Application Default Credential)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

In python, and for storage API, you can use this, as [described in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python)

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

Like this, you don't need any service account. In local, perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` to load your own credential as default credential and use the same default constructor in your code.